# OpenCL's enqueueWriteBuffer causes __memcpy_sse2_unaligned segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, opencl, memory-alignment

I have the following OpenCL code, using the C++ Wrapper and Intel's OpenCL toolkit:

```
#include <Eigen/StdVector>

...

typedef Sample_t float
typedef std::vector<Sample_t, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Sample_t> > SampleArray;

...

SampleArray data(ns * nt);

...

mdata = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(Sample_t) * data.size());
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(mdata, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(Sample_t) * data.size(), &data[0]);
```

When it is compiled with -O3, march=native and mtune=native flag, it causes the following segmentation fault coming from TBB code:

> __memcpy_sse2_unaligned() at memcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:116 0x7ffff6e64ba4

Without any optimizations, the program runs fine.

I traced the problem to the queue.enqueueWriteBuffer call, without it I have no problems whatsoever.

I have tried to comment out portions of the code that modify the variable "data", in case I was accessing invalid memory positions, but the problem persists.

If I remove the aligned_allocator from the std::vector, the build without optimizations also starts to break.

In total I have 70MB that I'm trying to store in this buffer, far less than the 3.8GB reported by CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE. But if I reduce the size of the array, the problem stops. The size that I tried in this later case was 5.

I also decided to print the address allocated by the vector and it is 0x7f21b797f010, so it is aligned to at least 16 bytes.

EDIT: Regarding multithreading, the creation of the array, as well as the OpenCL operations happen in the same method, and in the main thread. The command queue was not created with asynchonous flags, and there is a flush() operation after the buffer write.

What could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: The downvoter could, please, clarify the reason, as well as the close request for being off topic?

Comment: As you're using an async write, are you ensuring the SampleArray is not destroyed/resized until the `enqueueWriteBuffer` operation is guaranteed to have completed?

Comment: @pmdj The creation of the array, as well as the OpenCL operations happen in the same method and in the main thread. I have edited the question with more information.

Comment: clFlush will not guarantee that the copy operation will complete, just that it will start. You need to either wait for the event to fire, or pass true as the "blocking" argument. OpenCL is probably still busy copying your data when the vector goes out of scope.

Comment: Indeed, adding a clFinish solved the issue. Please turn this into an answer formally so I can mark it.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you got it working. (And no, I don't know why someone downvoted/flagged your question; seems a legit problem to me. Some people on Stack Overflow are weird, don't let them get to you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed in the conversation in comments, the problem here is that the `enqueueWriteBuffer()` operation is non-blocking (`CL_FALSE` passed as the *blocking* argument) and that the source buffer (`SampleArray` vector) goes out of scope before the underlying copy operation is guaranteed to have completed.

There are at least 4 possible solutions:

1. Use the blocking form of `enqueueWriteBuffer()`. As the documentation indicates, the source buffer will not be accessed once the function returns in that case.
2. Capture the returned event and call `clWaitForEvents()` or call `clFinish()` before the `SampleArray()` goes out of scope. This is only really preferable to the blocking variant if your program is doing anything substantial in the interim.
3. Keep the source data around for long enough.
4. Don't use the copying form of `enqueueWriteBuffer()`: create a buffer with a NULL source, map it into your application's memory space, write the data to it, then unmap it. This potentially avoids copying altogether, at least on integrated GPUs/APUs)

These are roughly in increasing order of parallelism/efficiency.